# Change imageview backgrounds on drop

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have created a drag and drop application that allows the user to drag 4 images from the top and put them in order at the bottom.  I have 4 image views on top and 4 imageviews on the bottom.  Bringing them down works perfectly, however when I attempt to move them side to side I run into problems.

I have 2 temporary imageviews where I set them equal to a imageview. If i move an image from image view 6 to image view 5, it is supposed to swap the images, but it just changes image view 6 to what image view 5 was and image view 5 stays the same.

Here is the code snippet to where I am attempting to change the images

> **droppedSwap** is equal to the image the user chose to move
>   **dropTargetSwap** is equal to where the user wants the image to go

```
if (dropTargetSwap.equals(ivHero5) && droppedSwap.equals(ivHero6))
            {
                //set temp imageview that is equal to ivHero5
                ImageView tempDropTarget = ivHero5;

                //set temp imageview that is equal to ivHero6
                ImageView tempDropped = ivHero6;

                //supposed to set ivHero6 to ivHero5 image
                droppedSwap.setBackground(tempDropTarget.getBackground());// working

                //supposed to set ivHero5 to ivHero6 image
                dropTargetSwap.setBackground(tempDropped.getBackground());// not working
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're problem is  that by doing:

```
ImageView tempDropTarget = ivHero5;
ImageView tempDropped = ivHero6;
```

You're not actually creating temporary copies but rather references to the original objects, so when you do droppedSwap.setBackground() you're actually setting the ivHero6 background and when you do tempDropped.getBackground() you're getting the ivHero6 background that was changed earlier.
You should create a copy of the backgrounds, which are drawables using:

```
Drawable copy1 = ivHero5.getBackground().getConstantState().newDrawable();
Drawable copy2 = ivHero6.getBackground().getConstantState().newDrawable();
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you so much! I was zeroing in on what needed to be done but got stuck right there.